# How to know the effect of a variable that is in both the numerator and denominator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Say I have an equation where

> $$Y = \frac{ab + cd}{c + b}$$

How would I be able to tell what effect $b$ is having on $Y$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$$
Y = \frac{ab + cd}{c+b} = \frac{ab + ac + cd - ac}{c+b} = a + \frac{cd-ac}{c+b}
$$